# Data import using MLCP at the command lines errors if an exclamation mark is in the password parameter

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

Environment: Windows 7, MarkLogic 8, mlcp 8.0-5

Running an mlcp import in command line mode works correctly using admin/admin credentials but for an other account where the password has an exclamation mark the following error [edited] is generated:

```
17/07/18....ERROR contentpump.ContentPump: Error parsing command arguments:
17/07/18....ERROR contentpump.ContentPump: Missing required option: 
input_file_path.
```

Code used:

```
mlcp.bat import -mode local -host localhost -database MyDb -port 8000  
-username MyUser -password MyPwd! -input_file_path D:/MyProject/documents 
-output_collections urn:ABC:mydocuments
```

Swapping the positions of the "-output_collections" and "-input_file_path" parameters generates the following incorrect response:

```
17/07/18 14:49:14 ERROR contentpump.LocalJobRunner: java.io.IOException: 
com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.RequestPermissionException: Authorization 
failed for user
```

Is this an issue with the operation of the "hadoop-mapreduce-client-core library" and is there an option not involving a password change?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the exclamation point?  Most command lines have ways to escape special characters.  I'm not sure how you do this in windows.  You could try surrounding it in double quotes.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replying. I haven't on the basis I don't know what escapes are valid.

Answer (score 2):

As Sam said, you probably need to escape the bang. If that seems like too much trouble, you can also use an options file instead of fighting with the shell interpolation. See the following topic for details and examples:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/intro#id_36150

Comment: As per recent update to Sam's comment. The code is being run from Microsoft's TFS and as it will contain username and password data I'd rather not have the options file hanging around. Escaping the 'bang' is fin I just need to some pointers to find out what characters escape. I'll start for a hunt in DOS for escape characters and then look at Hadoop (maybe). Most probably I'll end up altering the password as a quick fix.